# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cairo_font_map_get_default'

Tags: python, cairo, pango, pycairo, pangocairo

If I try to run [this example](https://www.cairographics.org/cookbook/pycairo_pango/) from the cairo website, I get:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'cairo_font_map_get_default'
```

I guess I'm missing some packages? (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04)

However, I try to find the dev packages I would need, and the only answer I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302458/python-issues-with-pango-and-pangocairo), which is recommending something from the GTK2 stack, but if anything , I'm interested in GTK3, not 2.

Comment: did you mis-spell pangocairo ? I just tried it, and it works fine

Comment: how can I mispell something that I didn't write? :) I just used copy+paste

Comment: Did you call the file `pangocairo.py` perhaps? If so **don't do that**. You are masking the installed module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly suspect you called your Python file `pangocairo.py`. Don't do that, you are masking the `pangocairo` library, and are importing *your own script file* instead.

At best `pangocairo` is not what you think it is. Verify the path of the module with:

```
import pangocairo
print(pangocairo.__file__)
```

to see what file is *really* being imported. You probably will have to rename this file.

When you do rename the affected file, a `pangocairo.pyc` byte cache file may be left in the same location, which still will be imported. Make sure you remove that file altogether.

Comment: I called it like that, yes, but renaming it doesn't fix it, therefore I'm downvoting this

Comment: @knocte: I added additional advice. Do make sure you removed the `pangocairo.pyc` file that was left in the directory.

Comment: wtf, you were right, solved when I removed the pangocairo.pyc

Comment: this makes me realize that I hate python much more than I thought

Comment: @knocte: You'll get used to the module namespace issue. There are gotchas like this in **every** programming language. Python has fewer than most.

Comment: a language that has a gotcha as big like this and hasn't provided at least a better error message, is.... **facepalm**

Comment: All the info is there; had you posted the full traceback I would have pointed to the filenames in the traceback; these would have clearly shown you were importing the script itself.